# Python assign labels to the text data using positive and negative text files for sentiment analysis(Text analytics/mining)?

Tags: python-2.7, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, text-analysis

I am new to the text mining. I have data set of user comments on the job done by the technician.

Below is the dataset rows.

```
id    comments
1     That's not good job as it was not completed on mentioned time.
2     nice job
3    good job but not satisfied
```

Now here i do not have any labels and I want to do the sentiment analysis (find the polarity score and classify the comments into positive,negative and neutral class).

What I have done till now is that i took the text file having positive words and negative words from google. Then I looked into each comment using these text files and if word is present then assigned the respective label. But i am not getting expected values. All are getting the label as positive.

And one more problem is that in first comment there is word called **"not good"** which should be negative but in my positive text file if it is find word as **good** then it assigns the label as positive which is wrong.

Below is my code:

```
pos_words_list = [w.lower() for w in pos_words_list]
neg_words_list = [w.lower() for w in neg_words_list]

def assign_comments_labels(x):
    try:
        if any(w in x for w in pos_words_list):
            return 'positive'
        elif any(w in x for w in neg_words_list):
            return 'negative'
        else:
            return 'neutral'
    except:
        return 'neutral'



df['COMMENTS'] = df['COMMENTS'].str.lower()

df['labels'] = df['COMMENTS'].apply(lambda x: assign_comments_labels(x))

df[['COMMENTS','labels']].head()
```

output:

```
  id    comments                                                    labels
    1     That not good job was not completed on mentioned time.      positive
    2     nice job                                                    negative
    3     good job but not satisfied                                  neutral
```

Could anyone please tell me how do I achieve this. What is the proper way to assign the labels and perform the sentiment analysis. What else could I do for more exploration to get meaningful insights from the text data ?

Comment: If you don't want to roll-your-own, the `nltk` package is the best Python library to deal with text mining and classification. Here's a tutorial on [Sentiment Analysis using nltk](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html)

Comment: thanks Phil. I will try that one.